# How to calculate when an areostationary satellite would be unable to talk to earth?

Tags: mars, communication-satellite, geostationary

Consider an areostationary (geostationary but for Mars) satellite that communicates to Earth. Since on some orbits, Earth would be behind Mars from the point of view of the satellite, I imagine that it wouldn't be able to directly communicate with Earth during those periods (without using a relay of some kind). I would like to know how I would generate a table of each time Earth is directly unreachable, with the duration of each outage? An example table would be appreciated if created for some subset of the 2070s.

"Bonus points" for more accurate answers, especially those that would be accurate up to 100 years in the future.

I've spent some time looking around for answers and playing in python with PyEphem but was unable to figure out how to do this. After more research it looks like this might be possible with spiceyPy using its subpnt method with the technique described in the comments, but I'm way out of my depth when it comes to figuring out how to actually use that. I've also been thinking about somehow converting the positions of the satellite and Earth into a global cartesian coordinate system and drawing a line between the two, simulating with timesteps forward until there's an intersection with Mars planet as an approximation technique.

Comment: I would think that there are formulae to calculate the sub-earth point on Mars. That is, what is the latitude and longitude on Mars where Earth is at the zenith. If such information exists, you can calculate when the aero-sat is at opposition with the Earth (as seen on Mars). Based on the sub-Earth latitude and the distance to the areo-sat, you can calculate if the areo-sat is behind Mars as seen from the Earth or if clear of Mars.

Comment: I think this makes sense: supposedly spiceyPy has a sub point function that might work to get that info, and then I'd just need a function that given the long/lat of the sub-earth point, does Mars eclipse Earth from that altitude.